# How to solve Turborepo npm build issues

Tags: reactjs, npm, monorepo, turborepo

Context - we are transitioning to a monorepo using Turborepo with React and Cypress apps.

While building the React app using the `npm run build` command we are receiving the following error:

```
:build: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './version' in '/Users/****/Projects/****/app/node_modules/graphql'
:build: Did you mean 'version.mjs'?
:build: BREAKING CHANGE: The request './version' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
:build: (probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
:build: The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
:build: Add the extension to the request.
```

What we have tried so far:

1. Modifying the `package.json` type property to either `commonjs` or `module`.
2. Modifying the actual line in the aforementioned package to have the specified suffix.

Thanks in advance!